# How to work with case statements and string matches ruby

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

```
def self.determine_created_at(created_at)
            Rails.logger.info(created_at)
    case(created_at)
    when "Today"
        where(created_at: Date.today)
    when "Yesterday"
        where(created_at: Date.yesterday)
    when "This Week"
        where(created_at: (Date.today.at_beginning_of_week..Date.today.at_end_of_week))
    when "This Month"
        where(created_at: Date.today.at_beginning_of_month..Date.today.at_end_of_month)
    when created_at.upcase.include?("MONTHS")
        where(created_at: (created_at.split[1].to_i.month.ago.to_date.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month))
    when created_at.match(/Hours/) 
        Rails.logger.info "INSIDE HOURS"
        where(created_at (created_at.split[1].to_i.hours.ago..DateTime.now))
    when created_at.upcase.include?("MINUTES")
        where(created_at: (created_at.split[1].to_i.minutes.ago..DateTime.now))
  end
end
```

This is the code I am using for a small filter implementation. When I send a string like `8 hours ago` it is not working properly. That is the required case is not being selected and `INSIDE HOURS` is not being printed. Neither are "Minutes" and "Months" working. The rest are working.

Comment: Did you try `when /Hours/`?

Comment: It works.. that was so so stupid! Ugh! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are specified directly in the `when` clause of `case` statements:

```
case created_at
...
when /hours/
...
end
```